# fragment shader if statment and loading array of mat4 into uniform

Tags: opengl, glsl, lwjgl

I have problem with if here, for reasons uknown to me, it dosnt work.
When i delete if statment or malualy write shadowMap[0] 1 or 2 it works fine, but with if i just get set of white triangles and squares.

here is part of my frag shader

```
float shadow(float bias)
{
    float visibility = 0;
    int index=1;    
    if(gl_FragCoord.z<1.0){
        index=0;
    }       
    vec4 shadowCoord=depthPV*vPos;
    if ( texture(shadowMap[index], shadowCoord.xy).z  <  shadowCoord.z+bias){
      visibility = -1;
    }
    return visibility;
}
```

Other problem i have is with loading array of mat4 into uniform here is code i tried, but it dosnt work, i use lwjgl 3 libery in java

```
        shadowPVs=GL20.glGetUniformLocation(pId, "shadowPVs");          
        ByteBuffer shadowPVbuff=BufferUtils.createByteBuffer(shadePV.length*16*4);
        for(int i=0;i<shadePV.length;i++){
            for(int v=0;v<16;v++){
                shadowPVbuff.putFloat(shadePV[i].val[v]);
            }
        }
        shadowPVbuff.flip();

        GL20.glUniformMatrix4f(shadowPVs, shadePV.length, false, shadowPVbuff);
```

and in shader

`uniform mat4 shadowPVs[3];`

Comment: @problem 1: you did not include which glsl version you are targetting, but in earlier glsl versions, it is not allowed to index sampler arrays with non-constants. I.e. the 3.3 spec it states: Samplers aggregated into  
arrays within a shader ... can only be indexed with integral constant expressions.

Answer (score 0):

What you are trying to do is *not possible* with current GL.

As @gemse already pointed out in the comments, the relevant part of the [GLSL 3.30 spec](https://www.opengl.org/registry/doc/GLSLangSpec.3.30.6.clean.pdf) is:

> Samplers aggregated into arrays within a shader (using square brackets
>   [ ]) can only be indexed with integral constant expressions (see
>   section 4.3.3 “Constant Expressions”).

In GL 4, this constraint has been somehwat relaxed, but not far enough. In the most current [GLSL 4.50 spec](https://www.opengl.org/registry/doc/GLSLangSpec.4.50.pdf), the statement is:

> When aggregated into arrays within a shader, samplers can only be
>   indexed with a dynamically uniform integral expression, otherwise
>   results are undefined.

With *dynamically uniform* being defined as

> A fragment-shader expression is dynamically uniform if all fragments
>   evaluating it get the same resulting value. When loops are involved,
>   this refers to the expression's value for the same loop iteration.
>   When functions are involved, this refers to calls from the same call
>   point. This is similarly defined for other shader stages, based on the
>   per-instance data they process. Note that constant expressions are
>   trivially dynamically uniform. It follows that typical loop counters
>   based on these are also dynamically uniform.

Your index depends on data which can vary per fragment, so you are getting undefined results.