# Is glVertexAttribpointer used only for vertex, UVs, colors, and normals ? Nothing else?

Tags: opengl, glsl

I want to incorporate a custom attribute that varies per vertex. In this case it is assigned to location=4 ... but nothing happens, the other four attributes vary properly except that one. At the bottom, I added a test to produce a specific color if it encounters the value '1' (which I know exists in the buffer, because I queried the buffer earlier). Attribute 4 is stuck at the first value of its array and never moves.

Am I missing a setting ? (something to be enabled maybe ?) or is it that openGL only varies a handful attributes but nothing else ?

```
#version 330 //for openGL 3.3

//uniform variables stay constant for the whole glDraw call
uniform mat4  ProjViewModelMatrix;
uniform vec4  DefaultColor;  //x=-1 signifies no default color

//non-uniform variables get fed per vertex from the buffers
layout (location=0) in vec3 coords;       //feeding from attribute=0 of the main code
layout (location=1) in vec4 color;        //per vertex color, feeding from attribute=1 of the main code
layout (location=2) in vec3 normals;      //per vertex normals
layout (location=3) in vec2 UVcoord;      //texture coordinates
layout (location=4) in int  vertexTexUnit;//per vertex texture unit index

//Output
out vec4 thisColor;
out vec2 vertexUVcoord;
flat out int  TexUnitIdx;

void main ()
{
    vertexUVcoord = UVcoord;
    TexUnitIdx=vertexTexUnit;

    if (DefaultColor.x==-1) {thisColor = color;} //If no default color is set, use per vertex colors
    else {thisColor = DefaultColor;}

    gl_Position = ProjViewModelMatrix * vec4(coords,1.0); //This outputs the position to the graphics card.

    //TESTING
    if (vertexTexUnit==1) thisColor=vec4(1,1,0,1); //Never receives value of 1, but the buffer does contain such values
}
```

Comment: I'll have do add a warning which is not directly addressing your question, but the `layout (location=4) in int  vertexTexUnit;//per vertex texture unit index` part. This gives the impression that you want to index different samplers in an array based on a vertex attribute. But this is _not possible_ in GL3.x, see [my answer here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/30187813/fragment-shader-if-statment-and-loading-array-of-mat4-into-uniform/30199513#30199513) for details. YOu might get away with the `flat` index in GL 4.x, as the resulting value should be dynamically uniform...

Comment: @derhass: Yes, the flat attribute is what make it go through. It is working fine so far on GL3.0, GL3.3. I am getting 6 textures per draw call on six different surfaces as we speak.

Comment: Well, it is at least not backed by the spec in GLSL < 400, so it might break on some implementations.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Because the `vertexTexUnit` attribute is an integer, you must use `glVertexAttribIPointer()` instead of `glVertexAttribPointer()`.

You can use vertex attributes for whatever you want.  OpenGL doesn't know or care what you're using them for.

Comment: Gaaaaahh, another little gotcha in the openGL ocean. Yes that was it. Thank you !